# How to upload any type of file in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-file-upload

I want to accept any type of file from the user and save it in the database. I am using following code:

In HTML file :

```html
<input type="file" name="file_name" required>
```

But when I try to access the file in **views.py** it throws the Exception as `'file_name'`.

```py
file_name = request.FILES['file_name']
```

In the same field when I select some image. The image is stored in the media folder.

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**views.py**

```py
try:
    file_name = request.FILES['file_name']        
except Exception as e:
    print('In Exception')
    print(e)
```

Exception shows after printing `In Exception` as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kambl\PycharmProjects\Linkingzz - 08 Mar\Linkingzz\Linkingzz\Linkingzz\app\views.py", line 534, in article
    file_name = request.FILES['articleName']
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'articleName'
```

**models.py**

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    FileField = models.FileField(upload_to='Order - Articel Files', blank=True, null=True)
    ImageField = models.ImageField(upload_to='Order - Featured Images', blank=True, null=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Comment: Show your configurations for `media` in settings.py, and show your `urls.py` where you configured.

Comment: Provide full exception

Comment: I have made changes....

Comment: remove the "try ... except"  and post the full error message

Comment: Hello @ManojKamble You've to check full exception by removing your try except block and if you're uploading file make sure you've add [`enctype='multipart/form-data'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526286/14457833) inside your form tag.

Comment: I have added the full error

Comment: can you show the models.py? or full exception?

Comment: Check models.py file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added "enctype="multipart/form-data" In form tag and it's working fine.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```